# Can I run Python 2.7 and Python 3.6 builds on same installation of anaconda? How?

Tags: python, refactoring, anaconda

I currently have a Python 2.7 build of anaconda. But I'm facing issues following some other Python 3.6 codes. So, I am looking for a solution by which I can keep both versions of anaconda running in the same build.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: @whitek1ght, you can use different [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)s to run a specific version of Python.

Comment: Anaconda is a *Python distribution*, i.e. an interpreter with a prebuilt set of libraries. You cannot have two different versions of an interpreter. You can create a `conda` environment with whatever interpreter you'd like